# `bad trailer dictionary` when processing PDF generated with lualatex

Tags: luatex, pdf, ghostscript

For several reasons, my workflow includes running my (Lua)LaTeX PDF through ghostscript like this:

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input.pdf
```

Since recently (TeX Live 2021 end of year updates, but still applies to TeX Live 2022), it results in:

```
The following warnings were encountered at least once while processing this file:
    bad trailer dictionary

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> LuaTeX-1.15.0 <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

There is at least one visual effect, that is PDF ToC being dropped.

Is anyone else seeing the same? Where should this report be directed to?

Comment: ghostscript has a new pdfwriter. Try with the option `-dNEWPDF=false`  to use the old one. If that works you should make a small complete example and then report at the ghostscript bug tracker. (It is probably related to this bug https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=705218 )

Comment: Seems indeed to be related to that new pdfwriter. Will comment on upstream bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in upstream ghostscript 10.0 release.